# Google Analytics Dashboard: week-by-week view

Tags: google-analytics

Setting up Google Analytics Dashboard allows webmasters to get a weekly progress report of marketing achievements & keep a finger on what's going on at web properties.

However, by default, the dashboard always displays a day-by-day report, which isn't actionable in markets, where meaningful improvements happen on a week-by-week, or month-over-month basis.

Is there any way the default view (and reports sent out via email) can be set to display week-level resolution, as opposed to day-level resolution? (ie, repro: analytics -> site -> Standard reports -> audience -> overview -> right side of the window, click "weeK")

Many thanks!

Comment: I had read the whole Google's help about dashboards and didn't find  any options to do that.

Comment: Don't know about emails, but the URL changes when you change to "week".. can you just bookmark that for a shortcut?

Comment: @joshuahedlund you're talking about the default landing page of analytics (Audience -> overview); question is specifically about the private / custom dashboards where you can pin gadget from any other page

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question a while back and also couldn't find a solid answer anywhere. However, I did something that seemed to please my clients that I believe should get you the results you're looking for. I'll explain my solution, and maybe you find it beneficial.

My clients wanted weekly Google Analytics reports with a monthly view of data, and I needed the emails to be automated because I'm too busy to continually pull reports for 30 clients. But, when you set dashboard emails to send weekly, Analytics will only display data for the past 7 days. To solve this problem, I scheduled four separate dashboard emails containing the exact same information to be sent on a monthly frequency on the 1st, 8th, 15th, and 22nd of each month. When the client receives emails on those dates, they contain a month view because they were scheduled as "monthly" emails, even though they receive the emails approximately every 7 days.

I hope that helps you solve your problem. I may come back and try to edit this for clarity at a later point.

Comment: I am the end-consumer of the KPIs, and they need to be actionable (so handwaving it won't work). Day-to-day datapoints aren't showing anything actionable, because marketing achievements make meaningful contribution on a weekly basis only (eg. site is a "monday site" -we've got natural ups on Monday). So I need *aggregation* of ALL data that happened over the week into a *single* datapoint -similar to the audience -> overview -> week data. So no, this does not solve my problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you creating custom dashboards? For example, I send my clients one weekly custom dashboard report that contains the following data: visits, unique visits, % new visits, avg. visit duration, bounce rate, pages/visit, pageviews, unique pageviews, visits by source/medium, and goal completions by source. All that data is compared to the previous period which is define by me, so it can be a week, month, quarter, etc.

Comment: After reading the comments and your question a few more times, I think I now fully understand what you're asking. My thought, though, is no matter if you're looking at a week-level resolution or a day-level resolution, the data itself won't change for the set period. Using your example: analytics -> site -> Standard reports -> audience -> overview -> right side of the window, click "week", will not show me different data than: analytics -> site -> Standard reports -> audience -> overview -> right side of the window, click "day", but the visual graph will change.

Comment: See that graph change? While the individual datapoints are the same, the aggregation of the data changes radically depending on whether you're looking at it on a day, week, or month cohort. And yes, question is specifically about custom dashboards.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of years later I'm facing the same issue.
My solution is to change the type to BAR graph and group the date by "Week of the year". Make sure to sort the graph by "Week of the year" by clicking the little arrow next to it while editing.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Google Analytics allows dates to be bookmarked, however it does not allow relative dates into the URL.  So when you bookmark a GA URL, the dates in that URL are frozen in time and never update as new data comes in. To work around this, you need software that updates the dates dynamically.

I created [a page on ostermiller.org that allows me to see a wide variety of views into my Google Analytics account with dynamic relative dates](http://ostermiller.org/calc/ga.html).

To use this page:

- Find your Google Analytics Report ID in the URL when you are looking at a graph on your Google Analytics.  It will have a format like `a00000000w00000000p00000000`
- Copy and paste this ID into the "Google Analytics report ID" box.
- Use the `Set` button to set the report ID.
- Now you will see lots of links such as "4 Weeks by Day" and "6 Months by Week".
- Before you click on the links, *bookmark the page on ostermiller.org* that now has `#gaid=` in the URL.
- Use this bookmark to access your Google Analytics account -- the links will automatically update with new dates in the URL.

It is also possible to create bookmarklet (javascript powered bookmark) to take you to the view that you want in one click.  See: [Changing default date range in Google Analyics?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/42564/changing-default-date-range-in-google-analyics/) and [Google Analytics Kiosk: URL that compares current month to last, and is permalink](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43647/google-analytics-kiosk-url-that-compares-current-month-to-last-and-is-permalin/)

Comment: Tank you for your answer Stephen. I know how to get "Weeks by weeks" views on graphs. Does your solution is working for Dashboard (I do not succeeded)?

Comment: Stephen, this is useful for deep-linking to report, but not for dashboards that are eg. sent out as weekly reports via email. Also tried hacking the URL (eg. visits weekly adds "%26overview-graphOptions.selected%3Danalytics.nthWeek/" ) to no avail. Any other suggestions?